# How can a C# global symbol be set to a value?

Tags: c#

I want a global symbol TEST2 to equal 111 in all my .cs files.
How is this done in C#?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ALPHA_CONTROLLER_CLI
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int blah = TEST2;
        }
    }
}
```

but TEST2 has error: "does not exist in current context"

Comment: You can create a public static class with a public static property `TEST2`

Comment: `public static readonly int TEST2 = 111;` or `public static int TEST2 => 111;` Terrible practice, but good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn’t such a thing as global variable in c#. Everything should be contained in a `class`. That being said, you can create a class or a set of classes only for these types of constants. It’s better to also mark these classes as static (see [static classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members)) if you intend to only store constants and static members. It is also better to properly categorize these constants using a proper class name.

```
public static class Constants
{ 
  public const int Test2 = 111;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a class for declaring the global variable

```
class A
{
    public int TEST2 = 10;
}


class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // instance of class A
        A a = new A();
        Console.WriteLine("First: " + a.TEST2);

        a.TEST2 = 5;
        Console.WriteLine("Last: " + a.TEST2);

        int something = a.TEST2;
        Console.WriteLine("Something: " + something);
    }
```

If you want your variable as a constant use something like this:

```
class A
{
    public const int TEST2 = 10;
}


class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int something = A.TEST2;
        Console.WriteLine("Something: " + something);
    }
}
```

Hope that works for you :)

Comment: If you want to store global value, you should create a static class with that value